# What age was Darth Vader when he finally died?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith, darth-vader, return-of-the-jedi

What was the exact age Darth Vader was when he finally dies at the end of Return of the Jedi?

Comment: ***finally***? Were you waiting for him to croak or something?

Comment: @corsiKa I sure was.  Had a good deal of money riding on it.

Answer (score 43):

### The best info available suggests that he was **45** when he died.

To determine this, we need to use a few sources. Note that some of these are no longer considered fully canon.

- According to this post by [Leland Chee](http://web.archive.org/web/20070621170525/http://forums.starwars.com/thread.jspa?threadID=125719&tstart=100), Anakin was born in 41.**9** BBY.
- Based on various cast interviews, we know that Anakin was aged 9 in Episode I (and that this film takes place in 32 BBY).
- According to the [Del Rey New Essential Chronology](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Chronology) the Battle of Endor takes place in 4.**1** ABY

That means Vader/Anakin died **.7** of a standard Galactic Year (approx 8 months) before his 46th birthday. Even taking into account that a galactic standard year is longer than an Earth year (368 days versus 365), there's not enough of a different to be important to our calculations.

Comment: That's young :( he was created by the mediclorians, aka god

Comment: Next: When was Darth Vader's Birthday? ;o

Comment: @MajorStackings That's easy - January 25th of course.

Comment: I would have thought May the Fourth. :)

Comment: @DarthSatan - Haha. Very droll indeed.

Comment: Please note that the two dates above are no longer considered canonical since the [great purge](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/) however Anakin's age (9) and the date of the Battle of Endor (4ABY) have been confirmed in various interviews.

Comment: @mossberg: at risk of being flippant, it's a lot older than Jesus, and he was created by God aka God ;-)

Comment: Man I just had this exact conversation at work yesterday...

Comment: @MajorStackings - Assuming a standard year is identical to an Earth year, then his birthday is on or around October the 8th.

Comment: @Richard I'm still trying to figure out how Chahk pulled my birthday out of the hat.

Comment: He looked terrible for his age.  I suppose having your skin burned off in a volcano will do that to you.

Comment: A standard year is not 365 days like on earth btw

Answer (score 6):

### Lets Do The Math

So we know that he was Age 9 during *The Phantom Menace*.

And we know from the conversation with Anakin and Obi-Wan in the turbolift at the beginning of *Attack of the Clones* that it takes place 10 years later

> Obi-Wan: Calm down Anakin.
>
> Anakin: Sorry master, I'm just nervous I haven't seen her **in ten years.**

That puts him at 19 when the Clone Wars start.

Another 3 years pass in between Episode II and III putting him at 22.

After that we know that Luke was 19 in *A New Hope* putting Vader at 41.

Another 3 years pass Putting Luke at 22 and Vader at 44.

After that only one more year passes until Epidode Six putting Luke at 23 and Vader at 45 years when he died.

Comment: The problem with working it out this way is that we don't know if they mean ten years precisely. Add a few months onto each calculation and you can end up being as much as a 2-3 years out by the end.

Comment: True but that is true of any equation all we have are rough approximations there is really no way to get an exact answer

Answer (score 0):

Anakin Skywalker was born at 41 BBY and dies at 4 ABY, the same year Yoda dies and it turns out Anakin/Vader dies at around 44 or 45 years old.

Comment: Did you see the other answers with much more information and sources?

Answer (score 0):

In the Star Wars sourcebook printed in 1987 Obi Wan is 60+ years of age and Vader is supposed to be a couple of years younger. However after they had the prequels out Lucas has been thorough in adjusting this info.

Comment: Can you offer a quote?